# Create Shareable Links in React Router

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-router, router

I am currently working on [app.wavetv.co](http://app.wavetv.co)

When someone goes to a new page, the url is app.wavetv.co/(channel name). However when I try to refresh this page, it says page not found. I am using the React Router to handle navigation and Netlify as my hosting. Not sure what I am doing wrong here, because it is important that they can share these links.

Here is the code:

https://github.com/wave-tv/wave-tv/blob/master/src/pages/channels.js

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first call GET /some_path try to download the `<SomePathComponent />` when it should be like `<Index><SomePathComponent /></Index>` since you have no logic on your server for handling that request (since React Router is supposed to do it)

Hash History
The idea is by appending a # to the end of the root of your URL, anything after that # won’t be sent to the server. So if the URL was happ.wavetv.co/#/path, the browser would make a GET request to app.wavetv.co, get back all the JavaScript, React Router would then load, see /path, and show the proper view for that route. React Router provides a [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) component you could use that will get you hash based routing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you'll need to use SSR (Server side rendering) also known as isomorphic, I recommend you to visit Next.js which is a very nice framework that creates an ssr react app ready to go, very similar to create-react-app so you won't have to deal with webpack and other annoying things.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to webpack.config.js:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```